# Running a linux command in C++ program

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to run the following in a c++ program:

```
string cmd("strings -n 3 < BinaryFile > ascii.txt");
system(cmd.c_str();
```

`BinaryFile` is a string that contains `/home/test/BinaryFile`

When I run it like so, I get the following output:

```
sh: BinaryFile: No such file or directory
```

If I try the following:

```
string cmd("strings -n 3 < BinaryFile.c_str() > ascii.txt");
system(cmd.c_str();
```

I get these errors:

```
sh -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('
sh -c: line 0: 'strings -n 3 < Binaryfile.c_str() > ascii.txt
```

How can I get this to run properly?

Comment: Firstly, make sure you can run the command successfully on bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct your command line explicitly:

```
string cmd("strings -n 3 < " + BinaryFile + " > ascii.txt");
system(cmd.c_str());
```